# How to access S3 bucket through HTTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have an EC2 instance in public subnet with default NACL and try to connect to S3 bucket through internet. My EC2 has a IAM role that allows access to this S3 bucket. S3 bucket has no bucket policies.

I want to connect to this S3 through HTTP, not HTTPS (for testing purposes). To do that, I changed outbound rule for security group to accept only 80 port.

When I try to access this S3, the request gets stuck.

When I change outbound rule for security group to accept only 443 port, the connection works.

[image]

Anyone knows why port 80 is not working ? How can I access S3 bucket through HTTP?

Comment: You probably need to tell the cli to use http instead of https, maybe by specifying a different endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you'll want something like:

```
aws --endpoint-url http://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com s3 ls s3://your-bucket
```

Where the endpoint URL comes from the Amazon S3 endpoints on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html).  All AWS cli commands default to HTTPS.  You must specify the endpoint to switch to HTTP.